# How good is Hard AI?

Tags: starcraft-2

If it were in a league, would it be bronze?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out your placement by comparing yourself to AI? Don't do that, just play the placement matches. However i think that Hard AI would probably be Bronze or at the bottom of Silver.

Comment: @PeterK - no, I'm top Silver myself right now. Just wondering about a friend who has a cracked version, and only plays vs AI. The AI seems to really suck.

Comment: Well since "your friend" is not "you," you can just play a game against the Hard AI to compare, no?

Comment: @BlueRaja - I could, but I'm not interested enough. I prefer to invest my time playing against real opponents ... and yes, my friend isn't me :) http://sc2ranks.com/eu/648904/ripper

Comment: Interesting question, I'd like to know that, too.

Comment: it's better than a medium ai and a little bit worse than an insane ai

Comment: Tell you friend to try [Green Tea AI](http://sc2.nibbits.com/assets/green-tea-ai/). The AI Level will be far better than Blizzard AI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obviously subjective, but from my experience:

- Medium - Low Bronze ( I could beat this when I started, and I placed in bronze)
- Hard - High Bronze ( I could beat this regularly before I was placed out of bronze, possibly low silver?)
- Very Hard - High Silver? (I can beat this regularly, and I'm ranked now mid-gold).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: it's probably somewhere around bronze or silver.

However, more importantly, the AIs do not play according to the modern metagame. This means playing against a human opponent in bronze or silver will still seem vastly different from playing against any of the AIs.

More specifically, the AIs usually don't follow any sort of modern build order. For example, if you're used to playing against the AI, you might expect an attack at around the 10-minute mark with Roaches and Hydras, but versus a human a Roach bust might come much sooner and is much more deliberate.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what strategy you play. The AI basically has only one good timing push, especially on "Very Hard". If you go for one base play it should be quite easy to stop the computer, create an expansion yourself and finally kill him.

Should you try to expand early the timing push is way harder to stop. Usually this involves you following a good build order and getting static defenses. The less defense you get the harder it gets, but you will have an advantage later on provided you survive.

My estimate is (provided you fast expand):

- Hard: Low Silver
- Very Hard: Low Gold

But if you fall for cheeses then it could look much worse, as real opponents do not follow the strict rules the AI has to obey.