# Starcraft HoTS AI vs League

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm playing starter edition so I can't get ranked normally.

I've just been playing through the AI beating them at very hard. How good is that for player leagues?

I've seen these: [How good is Hard AI?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9148/how-good-is-hard-ai)

But that seems outdated as the AI has been changed in HoTS.

Comment: Beating very hards means you're decent enough at micro and macro to do OK in gold league... as long as your opponents play in the same style as the AI. You'll definitely need to practice scouting and preparing to beat strategies the AI wouldn't use, especially all-in & harass strategies.

Comment: Just go play man! You had enough practice with the AI and you will probably find the adrenaline rushes you get vs real people very enjoyable. Don't mind your rank too much, i think by posting this you are competitive enough to end up in platinum with enough practice.

Comment: @MennoGouw I don't actually have starcraft 2 only the starter edition.

Comment: @Ben If the other question is outdated, then the generally accepted course of action is to open a bounty on it asking for updated information.

Answer (score 5):

Playing against the AI on various difficulties is actually incomparable to playing against a human. The AI acts in an already programmed way, which makes it easy for the human to adapt. The only way you can get better is to play versus a human, and adapt to the different scenarios / builds on the Ladder.

Playing against the AI, is solely for you to slightly improve your own skills, and trying out a variety of builds.

The fact that you can beat the AI on the hardest setting, simply means you have a broader understanding of the game mechanics, as an AI on Very Hard is harder to beat, which makes you better than you where when you started out.

Any player who didn't start out by playing versus an AI will as a minimum get into Bronze league. 
But a player who played versus the AI, is more likely to know more about game mechanics, which could place that player in a higher league - because that player, will beat the player with lesser understanding of the game mechanics.

My point is that its difficult to compare the AI to the Ladder.
You can have players who have never played StarCraft before, and get placed in Gold or Platinum. (I have a few friends who did this)

TIP: Play your 5 placement matches when you access HOTS, and then take some unranked matches for you to get used to your league.

Comment: Ranked / unranked have two separate MMRs, so it doesn't make sense to play your placements ranked, then continue unranked. Just play unranked always, or ranked always. Also keep in mind that they are exactly the same, but unranked simply doesn't show you any ranking information and doesn't place you in a division.

Comment: Sooner or later his probably doing Ladder. Might as well do the 5 placement matches and then adept to the league, if there are any Ladder Anxiety - Unranked is great. Are there any proof yet, that there are two separate MMRs, or just theories?

Comment: unranked uses your ranked MMR at first if you have one then the unranked and ranked MMR gets different.

Comment: @HugoTrudel, are there any solid proof that it works like this?

Comment: yes there is, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zn3-O4jYO7g, this videos explains it. The guy says that if you are ranked, your ranked MMR will be used as a base for your unranked one, if not, you'll have an unranked MMR starting from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

I would put that the Very Hard AI is equivalent to gold league as to beat hard AI you need ok macro or ok micro to beat them.

I can beat the Cheating AI (vision and resources) as a diamond player because the AI is horrible in engagements and will usually fight in bad spots (like chokes), and does not usually expand as quickly as it should in the early game.

Comment: I can beat the cheating AI when i'm lying in bed playing just with the mouse and executing a buildorder i make up as i go. I didn't play SC2 since a year when i already played so little that i dropped to platinum back then. I'd say cheating AI is around silver at most.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this would probably place you easily at top in Bronze and Top 25 in Silver after a while but I'm not sure about Gold as there are some really good Gold players who are Platinum rank but because the promotion system is a not good they stay in Gold rather than moving up. I'm in Platinum.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Bronze and can I also find the Very Hard AI fairly easy. So I guess the best to be said is that it doesn't compare to playing humans - only way to find out which league you're in is to play the ladder..